# Roots of the equation $2^x+2^{-x}=2 - {(x - 2)}^2$

Tags: inequality, roots

The number of real-valued solutions of the equation

$2^x + 2^{-x} = 2 - {(x - 2)}^2$

I am not sure how to solve this question and I am stuck.

My first guess was $2$ as it seems to me like a quadratic equation but this was not the answer. Can someone please give me an approach to this question?

Comment: Hint: $2^x+2^{-x}\ge 2$ and $2-(x-2)^2\le 2$ (and when does the equality occur?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh well as you can see in LHS there is a equation which has a minimum value 2

You can prove this using A.M-G.M inequality

That A.M > G.M for any two numbers

For this case the A.M of $2^x and 1/2^x$ is

$(2^x +(1/2^x))/2$

And the G.M will be 1

So it follows LHS $>= 2 $

And it can be easily found that the range of the function on RHS is $<=$ 2
So here exists only one solution that is $2^x$ = 1 for LHS which is x = 0

And for RHS at x = 2

We got contradictory values of x so this equation has no real solution.

[image: refer this pic]

See the graph {LHS = Blue } and { RHS = Red}

[image]

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:-Note that $2^x+2^{-x}\geq 2$ which occurs at $x=0$ and also the maximum value of $2-(x-2)^2$ occurs at $x=2$ . Make a graph for the two plots. I hope you know the basic curves. From that you'll see that there is no x for which LHS=RHS.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $a + \frac1{a} \ge 2$ for positive $a$ and hence $2^x + 2^{-x} \ge 2$.

Notice that $2 - (x-2)^2 \le 2$. Hence $$2 \le 2^x + 2^{-x} = 2 - {(x - 2)}^2 \le 2.$$

It follows that  $$2^x + 2^{-x}  =2 \text{${}$ ${}$ ${}$ ${}$  (1)}$$ and $$2 = 2 - {(x - 2)}^2 \text{${}$ ${}$ ${}$ ${}$  (2)}$$.

It follows from (2) that $x= 2$.

It follows form (1) that $x \ne 2$.

Hence there's no solutions.

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong; is it correct to say that k^x + k^-x >= 2 for any real number K ... if i deduce from this a+a^-1 >=2

Comment: @Md Ghaus Ali yes you can say this

Comment: @MdGhausAli, put k = x = -1. In this case $k^x + k^{-x} = -2$. So you need the condition $k > 0$. Moreover, tor negative $k$ and $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$ the value $k^x$ is not  well defined. For example, what doest $(-1)^{\sqrt{2}}$ mean?